# Qt CheckBox bind to property

Tags: qt, checkbox, view, model

I have a class like this

```
class foo
{
...
QString name
bool  active
...
}
```

Now I made a UI with the QtDesigner, include a LineEdit and a Checkbox. I use a `QStandardItem` and a `QDataWidgetMapper` for the name property, which works fine, but I have no idea how I can bind the checkbox to the active property.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Q_PROPERTY](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html) in your class so Qt Designer can see those properties
It's easier when you follow Qt coding style, for example use get & set:

```
class foo
{

    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ getName)
    Q_PROPERTY(bool active READ isActive)

public:
    QString getName() const;
    bool isActive() const;

private:
    QString m_name
    bool  m_active;
...
}
```